# Disable Office 365 on Windows boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, microsoft-office, office365, windows-services

I disabled the booting Office 365 when Windows boots using AVG PC Tuneup. I find it unnessecary to have an Office service running all the time when I barely use office. But when I disable this, I cannot run a single application of the office suite. All I get is the following error:

```
Something went wrong
We couldn’t start your program. Please try starting it again. If it won’t start, try repairing Office from “program and features” in the control panel.
```

Repairing the office suite through `Programs and features` in the control panel gives me another error:

```
Something went wrong
We’re sorry, but we are unable to start your program. Please ensure it is not disabled by the system. Error Code: 1058-13
```

So apparently this is because of the Office ClickToRun Service that must be running whenever you want to use any part of Office 365.

I would like to know if it is possible to have Office running only when I start any program of it. Thus blocking it from boot, start it when I run an Office program and kill the service when I close the program.

Some info:
My laptop is running Windows 10 x64 Pro.

Installed Office is 2016 (Office 365 University package) with separate Visio 2013 and 2016 installations

Comment: It is possible just not with the type of license you have.

Comment: Why would that be? please explain

Comment: Your license only gives you rights to a ClickToRun installer.  Only Enterprise versions of Office 2016 can be used with the traditional standalone installer.  You don't have a Enterprise license per the description you provided.

Comment: ok thanks. Though you just pointed me in a certain direction. Via http://www.office.com/myaccount I am able to download an offline install image. So I am going to try to install this instead of the click-to-run installer. And I wonder why my question is voted down. Is it that bad? I did my research otherwise i wouldnt ask here

Answer (score 0):

The offline installer will still utilize the click-to-run technology.  Those services need all need to be running for Office to work correctly.  The MSI (the more traditional installers most are used to) based installers are around if you can find them, but MS have been making them incredibly difficult to find.  You can still use your O365 account with these.

In the past you could get the trial version of Office 2013, sign in and activate it to full product with your O365 account.  Now most of these links just point to O365 trials.  If you have access to MSDN or VLA (volume license portal) you may be able to get a copy of the MSI based editions there.  That's about the only way to get them any more.

Answer (score 0):

I personally leave the clicktorun service disabled in services.msc. Until recently (which brought me looking through this), it would stay disabled until I started it back up, then all my Office programs ran fine. Once the document is open, it is safe to stop/disable clicktorun again, but be aware some functionality will disappear (I noticed Word could no longer access the custom dictionary).

I say until recently because I'm noticing it turns itself back to automatic start after some time. I rarely reboot my computer, so it must have updated or something.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're recommending as a solution?

Comment: Disable Microsoft Office ClickToRun Services in services.msc.